# Rearrange a LinkedList, producing endless end points

Tags: python, linked-list

I am now working on the problem of rearranging the linked list. The logic of the code feels right, but I encounter repeating the endless points of the linked list. I am not sure why, but feel more likely there is something wrong with the definition of the linked list. The question is:

> Given the head of a Singly LinkedList, write a method to modify the
> LinkedList such that the nodes from the second half of the LinkedList
> are inserted alternately to the nodes from the first half in reverse
> order. So if the LinkedList has nodes 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 ->
> null, your method should return 1 -> 6 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 -> 4 -> null.
>
> Your algorithm should not use any extra space and the input LinkedList
> should be modified in-place.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 10 -> 12 -> null Output: 2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 10
> -> 6 -> 8 -> null
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 10 -> null Output: 2 -> 10 -> 4 -> 8 -> 6
> -> null

My approach is:

```
def rearrange_linkedlist(head):
    # find the middle as the separating point
    middle = middle_linkedlist(head)
    # reverse the second part
    second_head = reverse_linkedlist(middle)
    while head and second_head:
        following_1 = head.next 
        following_2 = second_head.next 
        head.next = second_head
        second_head.next = following_1
        head = following_1
        second_head = following_2

def middle_linkedlist(head):
    slow, fast = head, head 
    while fast and fast.next:
        slow = slow.next 
        fast = fast.next.next 
    return slow

def reserve_linkedlist(head):
    current = head 
    previous = None
    while current:
        following = current.next
        current.next = previous
        previous = current 
        current = following 
    return previous
```

The set up of the linked list:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next 
    
    def print_list(self):
        temp = self
        while temp:
            print(str(temp.value) + ' ', end='')
            temp = temp.next 
        print()

def main():
    head = node(2)
    head.next = node(4)
    head.next.next = node(6)
    head.next.next.next = node(8)
    head.next.next.next.next = node(10)
    head.next.next.next.next.next = node(12)
    rearrange_linkedlist(head)
    head.print_list()
    
main()
```

And the result is:

```
2 12 4 10 6 8 8 8
```

with repeating 8. I am not sure what is wrong with it. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Whenever updating a pair of links, add an assertion to make sure they aren't both the same link.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue or not.  The last item on the first half is still pointing into the second half during the interleaving part of your code.  You've reached the end of the front of the list when it points to middle.

Comment: Thanks, @RaymondHettinger. The questions request the space complexity is O(1), so I updated the linked list in place. Would you mind explaining more about assertion?

Comment: Thanks, @FrankYellin. I think you are pretty close. Since I reversed the linked list in place, two linked lists pointed to the same tail and then to None. But I am not sure why the first linked list become endless, or without an end of None. Plz share more insights.

Answer (score 1):

It might be beneficial to split up all three steps into different helper functions. I.e., currently, you only have a helper function for finding the middle and reversing a list. You should probably also have one for merging the two lists (this is where the issue is in your current code):

```
def rearrange_linkedlist(head):
    middle = find_middle(head)
    reversed_second_half = reverse_list(middle)
    merge_two_lists_inplace(head, reversed_second_half)


def find_middle(head):
    fast = slow = head
    while fast and fast.next:
        fast = fast.next.next
        slow = slow.next
    return slow


def reverse_list(head):
    prev, curr = None, head
    while curr:
        curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, curr.next  
    return prev


def merge_two_lists_inplace(l1, l2):
    while l1 and l2 and l2.next:
        l1.next, l1 = l2, l1.next
        l2.next, l2 = l1, l2.next
```

The issue with your code is that the end of the first half of the linked list points to the end of the reversed second half. On the final iteration of your merge loop the list looks like this:

```
2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 10 -> 6 -> 8 -> null
                      ^    ^
                     head  second_head
```

When you assign `second_head.next = following_1` you're really assigning the final node to point to itself. Checking `second_head.next` in your loop condition terminates the loop when it's in the above state.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my codes, but still encountered similar issues.

Comment: Weird I tested the above code with `2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 10 -> 12 -> null` and got the expected response with no repeating 8's, i.e. `2 -> 12 -> 4 -> 10 -> 6 -> 8 -> null`. What input are you using that is failing?

Comment: I updated my code to include how I set up the linked list. Thanks for your help. Happy holidays!

Comment: I am not sure if l2.next is not None in your merge_two_lists_inplace function makes some effects. Thanks.